# Diff compiled java classes

Tags: java, diff, decompiler

I have a situation where my project was forked and compiled then the source deleted.  I have the source for the original project and the compiled jar (which I have decompiled)  Is there a way of doing a diff on the compiled code or a diff on the decompiled code to my repository code (ignoring comments etc) so I can see which code I need to re-import into my trunk.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your source code then decompiling it, and doing a diff on that? The decompiler is likely to produce code that doesn't resemble the original sources, but it should produce the same outputs on the same inputs (so unchanged classes/code should mostly get diffed out.)

Comment: That's a really good idea.  I'll give it a try